# geocode method not executing second time in the for loop

Tags: iphone, ios5, clgeocoder

I have written following code to find out the coordinates of list of countries.

```
  int count=[objCountries.countryName count];
CLGeocoder *geoCode = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    NSString *strCountry=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[objCountries.countryName objectAtIndex:i]];




        [geoCode geocodeAddressString:strCountry completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = place.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;

            NSString *tempLati=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.latitude];
            NSString *tempLongi=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.longitude];
            NSLog(@"-------------------------");
            NSLog(@"Country : %@",strCountry);
            NSLog(@" Latitude : %@ ",tempLati);
            NSLog(@" Longitude : %@ ",tempLongi);

            [objCountries.countryLatitude addObject:tempLati];
            [objCountries.countryLongitude addObject:tempLongi];
            [db insertAsiaCountry:strCountry :tempLati :tempLongi];
        }
    }];

}
```

}

In my countryName array there 20 objects available

**Problem:**
It's working Fine first time only. But Second Time when for loop executing
[geocode geo....] method is not calling. I Can't understand what to do ? Please Help. Thank You Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after this line..

```
    [db insertAsiaCountry:strCountry :tempLati :tempLongi];
```

add

```
[geoCode cancelGeocode];
```

even if error occurs try allocating geoCoder wihtin the 'for' loop

Answer (score 0):

You cant call any other `Method` in `for loop` because loop doesn't wait for until the work is finished. In your code you're calling `geoCode` method in `for loop` that is wrong. Try to call that method where your first method is being finished.

Comment: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 is coming. it's my first map application so i can't understand. What to do ? Please Help. can i do this task by another way? How?

Comment: answer modified with link to related question

Comment: First remove your loop try in with once with break points ... and check which is last method called when your method work is finished ...

Answer (score 0):

CLGeocoder is not intended to be used in a batch fashion as you are trying, so it is possible that subsequent requests are being rejected by the Apple servers. Have a look at the CLGeocoder reference documentation for guidelines on how to use this.

Copy and paste this data [need-a-list-of-all-countries-in-the-world](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv)  into a spreadsheet and save it as a csv. Add this file to the project. Then your app reads the file and creates the annotations as an array which you then add to the mapview.

Comment: I want to show pin on all the countries of the world. can i use another method to perform above task? Please Give me Some hint.

Comment: there's a data file available you can use - see link in my answer